# Why aren't objects of type 'id' initialized as pointers with a '*' in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

If I'm using Objective-C, here's how I declare an initialize an int:

```
int a = 1;
```

vs an object:

```
myObj *a = [[myObj alloc] init];
```

So this is a pointer to an object as denoted by the '*'. My question is, why aren't objects of type id declared this way? I.e., why is it this:

```
id genericObj;
```

and not:

```
id *genericObj;
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `id` means identifier. Identifier, like pointer, identifies the object. Identifier isn't the object itself.

You can always treat it as `typedef <some-mysterious-root-type>* id` if you want.

Answer (score 14):

Because id is defined as:

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

So it's already a pointer.

Comment: Yep, and you can easily find this out by command-double clicking on the word `id` in your code, which will take you to the definition.

Answer (score 3):

Pavel's answer is correct. Specifically, the "<mysterious-root-type> " is declared in objc.h as:

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```